# Dependency Injection Java Design Pattern Singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, dependency-injection, guice

I have some serious problems to understand, how to work with Dependency Injection and especially the singleton design pattern in a multithreaded environment.

Lets say i have a class:

```
public class DependencyOne {
    private DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;
    private DependencyThree dependencyThree;

    private Integer aNumber;

    public Foo(Integer aNumber, DependencyTwo dependencyTwo, DependencyThree dependencyThree) {
        this.aNumber = aNumber;
        this.dependencyTwo = dependencyTwo;
        this.dependencyThree = dependencyThree;
    }

    public doSomething() {
        dependencyTwo.doSomethingInDepOne(aNumber, dependencyThree);
    }


}

public class DependencyTwo {
    private DependencyThree dependencyThree;

    private aNumber;

    public Foo(Integer aNumber,DependencyThree dependencyThree) {
        this.aNumber = aNumber;
        this.dependencyThree = dependencyThree;
    }

    public doSomething() {
        dependencyThree.doSomethingInDepOne(aNumber);
    }


}


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

DependencyOne depTwo = new DependencyTwo("foo", "foofooo" .... <- just random config);
DependencyOne depThree = new DependencyThree(1,2,3,4,5,12,3,1235 <- just random config);

DependencyOne depOne = new DependencyOne(123, depTwo, depThree);

depOne.doSomething();




}
```

}

Now lets imagine, DependencyThree needs to be a singleton for various reasons, e.g. a JPA EntityManagerFactory, Centralized Logging or whatever at a global level, not per thread.

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DependencyThree());
```

A injector as far as i understand should only be created once.

Now my question, what is the best way to provide access to one instance of the DependencyThree Class.

**

> I don't want pass the dependencythree object through all other
>   classes, to get access of it.

**

At the moment i've just created a global singleton, which returns the instance, when i ask for one.
But some people say, that this is very bad design, (is it?).
How do i use dependency injection, on this setup, or shouldn't i use it at all ? This code is just raped a bit, it usually runs in a multithreaded environment.

Guice provides an @Singleton annotation, but this is per thread and not multihreaded.

How do i implement a global singleton in Guice, which is lazy created ?

Answer (score 3):

`@Singleton` in Guice means that once an instance of the target class is created, that very same instance is returned for all subsequent injection requests. The injector itself is thread safe and thus can be safely shared among threads.

Now, when does injection happens? Injection happens when you ask Guice to get an instance instead of using the `new` operator yourself.

You only have to ensure that there are no circular dependencies and that lifetimes of injected objects are clearly defined in such a way that `@Singleton` instances are created **before** depending classes and are possibly destryed **after**. By the way, there's nothing wrong with the singleton concept itself: sometimes you simply have a physical resource that can't be represented by more than on instance. It's the singleton pattern with Java `static` and lazy loading that it's often criticized because it's somewhat non-trivial to implement and there are safer alternatives (like a dependency injection framework)

Comment: So how do i do this in a multithreaded environment, because when the singleton is created in a thread, its only valid for this thread. I don't want to pass the instance through all other objects until it reaches the thread. What the benefit of using the @Singleton instead of static getInstance().

Comment: Your application always start from the main thread. In create your injector in the main thread, then the injector is global. What's your concern?

Comment: How do i access/create a class now, which has to contain the DependencyThree Singleton Instance, thats what i am woundering about.

Comment: Declare the dependency in the constructor and annotate it with @Inject. Standard Guice here...